# Worms in salmon

Tags: food-safety, fish, salmon

I bought fresh wild salmon today and when I got it home there was a tiny, live worm clinging to the plastic wrap inside. I overcooked it to 200 degrees Fahrenheit. So that should be enough. My friend said not to eat it as worms are a sign it's bad. It wasn't firm, it was a bit squishy like frozen fish even though it was fresh. The best before date is three days from now and it smelled fine (although I got the raw fish on my lip).

I've read this question but wondering if worms are a sign of fish being bad and if it's bad to eat even if fish is cooked properly and worms are no longer alive. [Is fresh cod with worms safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34467/is-fresh-cod-with-worms-safe-to-eat)

Edit: My question is 1) seeing worms in fish **is it a sign of fish being bad** or is it normal? It seems that people say not to eat it when they spot worms but if they are not noticed and frozen (sushi grade) or cooked properly we eat it. 2) **Is it just a disgust factor** or a real health concern (worms that are dead)? As I'm pretty sure most of us who eat fish end up eating the odd unseen dead worm in fish.

Comment: I would have returned the fish.

Comment: The answer won't be any different from the question you linked